# Wifi 802.11n drops randomly on my Macbook Pro 15"

Tags: wifi, macos, bootcamp, airport

Since I updated my Macbook to El Capitan, I can't stay constantly connected to my 802.11n WiFi. When I deasactivate it, or if i'm on Windows 10 using BootCamp, everything works fine, it's only on Mac OS X that it doesn't. I already tried everything (reinstalling OS X using CMD + R, reset SMC or PRAM, get the last updates, reseting WiFi settings) and I don't know what to do now, I'm not really willing to do a clean install since I'm not even sure that it will works ? I really don't know what to do...

Comment: Which version of `El Capitan` are you running?

Comment: On resetting your Wi-Fi settings, did you change the channel used?